# Performance Testing: Configuration of VTS

Tags: performance, performance-testing, load-testing, performancecounter, loadrunner

I am trying to use VTS (Virtual Table Server) in my scripts. But I'm getting the error  `globals.h:9: error: vts2.h: No such file or directory`.

Can anybody tell the solution for this? And if anybody has that `vts2.h`, can you please share it with me.

Comment: What is your theory, based upon the message and the Virtual Table examples and dependencies noted in the documentation?

Comment: Follow File-->Add Files to Script. to add headers to your script. Make sure you have access to LGs when you run the load test.